# How can I prevent or stop dictionary values from being nill?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a dictionary and a array of strings

The keys and values are generated with for loop

for some reason , all values in dictionary are nill.

1. Create a empty dictionary
2. Create a string array
3. Create for loop to generate keys and values

   1. keys become i.e. KEY_15.
   2. values would be a random number
4. Create for loop to check if the dictionary contains any of the elements in the array

   1. For each existing key that matches arr element, check if that key value is even or not i.e  if(arr[0] == dictionary key)
   2. if even, change dictionary value to 0 i.e. if arr contains element with string "Key_12" and dictionary contains a key with the name "Key_12", then value becomes 0.]

Making 2 for loops to match but problem still occurs

```
//Code Starts Here

var arr : [String] = ["KEY_10", "Bear", "KEY_23", "KEY_12"] // string array

var dic: [String : Int] = [:] //default dic

let ran: Int? = Int.random(in: 0...10) //generate random value

for i in 10...24{ //create elements to dic

    let iAsString = String(i)
    let stringWithZero = "KEY_" + iAsString
    dic[stringWithZero] = ran!
}

for x in arr{
    let dickeys: [String] = [String](dic.keys) //store keys

    let element = x
    for y in 0...dickeys.count-1{
        let dicKey = dickeys[y]

        if dicKey == element{  //never runs
            if dic[x]! % 2 == 0{
               dic.updateValue(0, forKey: x) //update value to 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Should compile now

Comment: What do you mean all values are `nil`? If you add `print(dic)` after your code, it outputs something like `["KEY_11": 3, "KEY_20": 3, "KEY_22": 3, "KEY_23": 3, "KEY_13": 3, "KEY_24": 3, "KEY_16": 3, "KEY_19": 3, "KEY_21": 3, "KEY_12": 3, "KEY_10": 3, "KEY_14": 3, "KEY_18": 3, "KEY_17": 3, "KEY_15": 3]`.

Comment: You should move your random number generation into the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, but it isn't efficient.

Here is a cleaned up version:

```
var arr = ["KEY_10", "Bear", "KEY_23", "KEY_12"] // string array
var dic: [String : Int] = [:] //default dic

for i in 10...24 { //create elements to dic
    dic["KEY_\(i)"] = Int.random(in: 0...10)
}

print(dic)

for x in arr {
    if let value = dic[x] {
        if value % 2 == 0 {
            dic[x] = 0
        }
    }
}

print(dic)
```

**Output:**

> ["KEY_19": 2, "KEY_22": 5, "KEY_11": 7, "KEY_21": 3, "KEY_15": 8, "KEY_14": 6, "KEY_12": 6, "KEY_17": 9, "KEY_23": 3, "KEY_16": 1, "KEY_18": 1, "KEY_24": 4, "KEY_10": 0, "KEY_13": 8, "KEY_20": 1]
>
> ["KEY_19": 2, "KEY_22": 5, "KEY_11": 7, "KEY_21": 3, "KEY_15": 8, "KEY_14": 6, "KEY_12": 0, "KEY_17": 9, "KEY_23": 3, "KEY_16": 1, "KEY_18": 1, "KEY_24": 4, "KEY_10": 0, "KEY_13": 8, "KEY_20": 1]

---

**Notes:**

1. You should move the generation of the random `Int` into the first loop so that each key potentially gets a different random value.
2. Let Swift infer types wherever possible (eg. use `var array = ["KEY_10"]` instead of `var array: [String] = ["KEY_10"]`).
3. Use *string interpolation* to create `"KEY_10"` through `"KEY_24"`.
4. To check if a key exists in a dictionary, just look it up.  There is no need to loop over all of the keys of the dictionary.  The value returned is an *optional* that is `nil` if the key doesn't exist.  Use *optional binding* to unwrap that `value`.

   ```
   if let value = dic[x] {
       // we only get here if key x exists
       // value is then the unwrapped value corresponding to key x
   }
   ```
5. `dic.updateValue(0, forKey: x)` is better written as `dic[x] = 0`.